# microsoft graph api error for work accounts

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I've been using Microsoft Graph Api's v1.0 Calendar methods for nearly 1 year.

Recently I noticed that we have a cors error when trying to get work or school accounts tokens from the front-end and made a request to the server and then returned the tokens.
And now `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars/` request returns

```
error: {
    code: "AuthenticationError"
    innerError: {
        client-request-id: "21192e40-2062-4ea6-809b-4325486c73c9"
        date: "2021-01-09T02:16:56"
        request-id: "21192e40-2062-4ea6-809b-4325486c73c9"
    }
    message: "Error authenticating with resource"
}
```

It seems all the `scopes` are set properly

[image]

The request returns the right response for private accounts. Does someone faced this issue and solved it

Comment: (1) Check the token and its values using https://jwt.ms (2) I believe you're calling these as delegated calls (as i see /me endpoint) and you're seeing the error, correct? (3) Test the same application call with same logged in user in Microsoft Graph explorer and see if it works. This will help you to isolate the issue.

Comment: Please check with your Azure/Office 365 administrator - whether the tenant has lapsed or the administrator for this tenant has disabled the application not to issue tokens?

Comment: Let me know if the above helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but my issue is very stupid. At first I did all the steps you described and it seemed that everything is ok.  
When I send the request to get tokens from my `back-end` It must be the final step. `Error authenticating with resource` means that my Microsoft 365 work account's subscription is passed. Very weird error response from Microsoft I think.

Comment: Glad to hear that its working now @Takhtak and it helped you to move forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case `Error authenticating with resource` means that my Microsoft 365 work account's subscription is passed) I just upgraded my account and everything works fine even with the wrong `scopes` that I have added in time of debugging

Answer (score 0):

First, I tried in my tenant to call the api ,I used following parameters and get response successfully. Of course I used a work account. The process is simple right?

So compared with your screenshot, I found that you've added many permissions, and could you check how many apis have you added into the 'scope'? By the way, I haven't found any apis under the 'Calendar' category.

[image]
[image]

Finally, I also tried add all the **graph** api permissions in your screenshot into 'scope' to get an access token, and with this token I get response too.

Hope to solve your problem, and if not, pls add more details such as grant flow and reqest parameters for token.

Comment: Thanks Tiny. In my case `Error authenticating with resource` means that my Microsoft 365 work account's subscription is passed)  I just upgraded my account and everything works fine even with the wrong `scopes` that I have added in time of debugging

Comment: Congratulations. And could you post your solution as the answer so that it may help others better.